# Can Azure Search Service be used to generate all the query tokens?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, lucene, azure-cognitive-search, stemming

Is it possible to get all the tokens for a particular query through the azure search API without linking the actual DB source? I want to have operations like stemming, removing stop words etc. performed on the query entered by the userand then pass it over to SharePoint to get the search results.

For instance if "ran" is the search query, the transformed query sent to SharePoint would include "run", "ran", "running" etc.. I tend to achieve something like what is demoed [here](https://alice.unearth.ai/)

From the documentation which I have browsed through it is stated that the Microsoft English analyzer does it. But what I am getting on using REST API exposed is just the root word (for instance "ran" returns "run" as the token).

Any help / pointers to the solution would be really appreciated.

P.S. Please let me know if any clarification is required.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, using the analyze API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) you will be getting the root words and not the tokens. 
Can you explain what is the scenario and why you need all the tokens? That way I can try to provide other solutions to your problem.

Thanks,
Revital.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I want to achieve is if the user enters "ran", the system, in my case SharePoint, should display results for "run", "ran", "running". 

Besides, the link you have shared is using Standard analyzer but I think what might, if at all, will work would be Microsoft English analyzer.